# How to check if a string starts with one of several prefixes?

Tags: java, string, if-statement

I have the following if statement:

```
String newStr4 = strr.split("2012")[0];
if (newStr4.startsWith("Mon")) {
    str4.add(newStr4);
}
```

I want it to include `startsWith`  `Mon` `Tues` `Weds` `Thurs` `Friday` etc. Is there a simple way to this when using strings? I tried `||` but it didn't work.

Comment: You mean you tried `"Mon||Tues"` etc.? Or did you use `newStr4.startsWith("Mon")||newStr4.startsWith("Tues") ...`? Either way, please define "it didn't work".

Comment: Are you trying to parse a date by any chance?? If so use SimpleDateFormat...

Answer (score 210, accepted):

Do you mean this:

```
if (newStr4.startsWith("Mon") || newStr4.startsWith("Tues") || ...)
```

Or you could use regular expression:

```
if (newStr4.matches("(Mon|Tues|Wed|Thurs|Fri).*"))
```

Comment: Is there any performance difference in the two methods you suggested?

Comment: @TheCrazyProgrammer Of course there is; matching via regular expressions is much more expensive than raw string method calls. Exact figures I cannot give, but this is the general consensus.

Answer (score 71):

Besides the solutions presented already, you could use the Apache Commons Lang library:

```
if(StringUtils.startsWithAny(newStr4, new String[] {"Mon","Tues",...})) {
  //whatever
}
```

Update: the introduction of varargs at some point makes the call simpler now:

```
StringUtils.startsWithAny(newStr4, "Mon", "Tues",...)
```

Answer (score 50):

No one mentioned [`Stream`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html) so far, so here it is:

```
if (Stream.of("Mon", "Tues", "Wed", "Thurs", "Fri").anyMatch(s -> newStr4.startsWith(s)))
```

Comment: great (and up-to-date) answer... btw `s -> newStr4.startsWith(s)` can be replaced by `newStr7::startsWith` to be clearer

Comment: How can I ignoreCase here ?

Comment: You can use String toLowerCase() function.

Comment: If **you already have an iterable**, use `.stream()`on it as mentioned [here](/questions/9790584/how-to-check-if-a-string-starts-with-one-of-several-prefixes#answer-69270770)

Answer (score 9):

A simple solution is:

```
if (newStr4.startsWith("Mon") || newStr4.startsWith("Tue") || newStr4.startsWith("Wed"))
// ... you get the idea ...
```

A fancier solution would be:

```
List<String> days = Arrays.asList("SUN", "MON", "TUE", "WED", "THU", "FRI", "SAT");
String day = newStr4.substring(0, 3).toUpperCase();
if (days.contains(day)) {
    // ...
}
```

Comment: Or [Arrays.binarySearch()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#binarySearch%28java.lang.Object[],%20java.lang.Object%29) if they search list is sorted :D

Comment: @BrendanLong a bit of an overkill for such a short list, but ok :)

Answer (score 6):

it is **even simpler** and **more neat** this way:

```
let newStr4 = strr.split("2012")[0];
if (['Mon', 'Tues', 'Weds', 'Thurs', 'Friday'].some(word => newStr4.startsWith(word))) {
    str4.add(newStr4);
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Of course, be mindful that your program will only be useful in english speaking countries if you detect dates this way.  You might want to consider:

```
Set<String> dayNames = Calendar.getInstance()
 .getDisplayNames(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK,
      Calendar.SHORT,
      Locale.getDefault())
 .keySet();
```

From there you can use .startsWith or .matches or whatever other method that others have mentioned above.  This way you get the default locale for the jvm.  You could always pass in the locale (and maybe default it to the system locale if it's null) as well to be more robust.

Answer (score 3):

Call `stream()` **on the list itself**  if you already have a List of elements:

```
List<String> myItems = Arrays.asList("a", "b", "c");
```

Like this:

```
boolean result = myItems.stream().anyMatch(s -> newArg4.startsWith(s));
```

Instead of using `Stream.of...`

Comment: This is important, else you will pass the list to startsWith which results in `java: incompatible types: invalid method reference
    incompatible types: java.util.List<java.lang.String> cannot be converted to java.lang.String`. IntelliJ hints this as _Reference to 'startsWith' is ambiguous, both 'startsWith(String, int)' and 'startsWith(String)' match_ which doesn't really help.

Answer (score 1):

```
if(newStr4.startsWith("Mon") || newStr4.startsWith("Tues") || newStr4.startsWith("Weds") .. etc)
```

You need to include the whole `str.startsWith(otherStr)` for each item, since `||` only works with boolean expressions (true or false).

There are other options if you have a lot of things to check, like [regular expressions](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html), but they tend to be slower and more complicated regular expressions are generally harder to read.

An example regular expression for detecting day name abbreviations would be:

```
if(Pattern.matches("Mon|Tues|Wed|Thurs|Fri", stringToCheck)) {
```

Answer (score 0):

When you say you tried to use OR, how exactly did you try and use it? In your case, what you will need to do would be something like so:

```
String newStr4 = strr.split("2012")[0];
if(newStr4.startsWith("Mon") || newStr4.startsWith("Tues")...)
str4.add(newStr4);
```

Answer (score 0):

If the task is to check if string matches any of the multiple values ignoring case, there are 2 options:

1. Based on the answer by `dejvuth`, you can do a batch-checking ignoring case as follows:

```
    if (Stream.of("Mon", "Tues", "Wed", "Thurs", "Fri")
        .anyMatch(s -> StringUtils.startsWithIgnoreCase(newStr4, s)));
```

2. Use the following method based on an implementation in StringUtils:

   ```
   public static boolean startsWithAnyIgnoreCase(
       CharSequence sequence, CharSequence... searchStrings) {
         if (!isEmpty(sequence) && !ArrayUtils.isEmpty(searchStrings)) {
           CharSequence[] searchStringsArray = searchStrings;
           int length = searchStrings.length;

           for (int i = 0; i < length; ++i) {
             CharSequence searchString = searchStringsArray[i];
             if (startsWithIgnoreCase(sequence, searchString)) {
               return true;
             }
           }
         }
     return false;
   }
   ```