# Java regex: First three digits are not 666

Tags: java, regex, jflex

I need to create a regex that returns true if the first three digits are not 666. Here are some examples:

66600abc - false

606asdfnh - true

600asdfasdf -true

I have tried this but I don't get the desired result.

```
System.out.println(Pattern.matches("[(^[(6)(6)(6)])][a-zA-Z0-9]*", "6660"));
System.out.println(Pattern.matches("[^6]{3}[a-zA-Z0-9]*", "606"));
System.out.println(Pattern.matches("[^666]{3}[a-zA-Z0-9]*", "506"));
System.out.println(Pattern.matches("[^666][a-zA-Z0-9]*", "636"));
System.out.println(Pattern.matches("[^666][a-zA-Z0-9]*", "666"));
```

Comment: `string.startsWith('666')`

Comment: Possible Duplicate of [How to check if a string starts with one of several prefixes?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9790584/how-to-check-if-a-string-starts-with-one-of-several-prefixes)

Comment: I need regex for this.

Comment: When you match a pattern in Java, you need to match the entire string.

Comment: `[^666]` == `[^6]`.

Answer (score 4):

Use a negative lookahead `(?!666)` and to match alphanumeric symbols, you may use `\p{Alnum}`:

```
System.out.println("6660".matches("(?!666)\\p{Alnum}*"));
```

Note that `matches()` anchors the pattern by default, there is no need for `^` and `$`.

Some [online tests](https://ideone.com/VD1N9D):

```
System.out.println("6660".matches("(?!666)\\p{Alnum}*"));        // false
System.out.println("66600abc".matches("(?!666)\\p{Alnum}*"));    // false
System.out.println("606asdfnh".matches("(?!666)\\p{Alnum}*"));   // true
System.out.println("600asdfasdf".matches("(?!666)\\p{Alnum}*")); // true
```

**UPDATE**:

Since that is JFlex, you may use this regex *if the minimum number of characters is 3* AND *only alphanumeric symbols are allowed*:

```
"^([a-zA-Z0-9]{1,2}$|[a-zA-Z0-57-9][a-zA-Z0-9]{2}|[a-zA-Z0-9][a-zA-Z0-57-9][a-zA-Z0-9]|[a-zA-Z0-9]{2}[a-zA-Z0-57-9])[a-zA-Z0-9]*"
```

If you need to allow any char, not just alphanumeric only, you may use replace `[a-zA-Z0-9]` with `.` and `[a-zA-Z0-57-9]` with `[^6]`:

```
"^(.{1,2}$|[^6].{2}|.[^6].|.{2}[^6]).*"
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/xhXbJj/2)

NOTE that you may find a similar pattern in my [previous **Regex: match everything but** SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37988661/3832970).

Comment: Hello Wiktor I am using jFlex and ? mark is not support in it.

Comment: Or just use `matches("666.*")` and add a `!` . i.e, `if (!.matches("666.*))` :P

Comment: Try `"([a-zA-Z0-57-9]\\p{Alnum}{2}|\\p{Alnum}[a-zA-Z0-57-9]\\p{Alnum}|\\p{Alnum}{2}[a-zA-Z0-57-9])\\p{Alnum}*` (or [`([a-zA-Z0-57-9][a-zA-Z0-9]{2}|[a-zA-Z0-9][a-zA-Z0-57-9][a-zA-Z0-9]|[a-zA-Z0-9]{2}[a-zA-Z0-57-9])[a-zA-Z0-9]*`](https://regex101.com/r/xhXbJj/1)) - that will require at least 3 chars in the input string. Is there a minimum character threshold requirement?

Answer (score 3):

Don't use Pattern.matches just to check a magic value.

If you want your string not begin with "666", just check with String.startWith(String):

```
class Test {
   public static Boolean isNotEvil(String str) {
     return !myString.startWith("666");
   }

  public static void main(String [] args)
  {
     System.out.println(Test.isNotEvil("azerty") ? "Not evil" : "Evil!" );
     System.out.println(Test.isNotEvil("66600abc") ? "Not evil" : "Evil!" );
     System.out.println(Test.isNotEvil("606asdfnh") ? "Not evil" : "Evil!" );
     System.out.println(Test.isNotEvil("600asdfasdf") ? "Not evil" : "Evil!" );
     System.out.println(Test.isNotEvil("666") ? "Not evil" : "Evil!" );
  }
}
```

Result:

```
 Not evil
 Evil!
 Not evil
 Not evil
 Evil!
```

Comment: I need regex for JFlex parser.

Comment: Why would you add a double negation?
First "Is**Not**Evil()", then return **!myString**.startsWith...

Answer (score 1):

You can try this one:

```
([^6]|.[^6]|..[^6]).*
```

Comment: rather "^((6|66)$|([^6]|.[^6]|..[^6]).*)"