# How to get a row from a file that starts with multiple prefixes

Tags: python-2.7

I'm trying to get the rows that starts with 's1', 's2'. Below is the code.

```
import os

f = open("test.csv","r")
lines = f.readlines()
f.close()

f = open("test.csv","w")
for line in lines:
 if (line.startsWith("s1") ||  line.startsWith("s2")) 
      f.write(line)
f.close()
```

When I run this script I'm getting syntax error near '||'. 
I looked into this link  and made changes accordingly - 
[How to check if a string starts with one of several prefixes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9790584/how-to-check-if-a-string-starts-with-one-of-several-prefixes)

Please let me know if I'm doing anything wrong.
FYI, I'm using Python 2.7.

Thanks!

Comment: `||` => `or`. This isn't C, java or whatever. Change that and you'll be fine. Voting to close as typo induced by lack of sleep :) not even downvoting because the rest of your code is ok (that's your lucky day)

Comment: I tried using 'or' and still got syntax error

Comment: BTW: `startsWith` => `startswith`. This isn't java casing (thank god). Post the full stacktrace of the error (using `or` please, at least _that_ is fixed)

Comment: I made this change  added : at the end and it worked . Thank you!!   if (line.startswith ("s1") or line.startswith ("s2")) :

Comment: glad we could help.