# Java : startsWith() with different prefix and not only one

Tags: java, startswith

I need to write some code to check the length of my input AND the beginning of it. Depending on those two parameters, I'll have to modify my input. I succeeded in checking the length of my input. But I struggle when I try to check the beginning of my input.

Here I am so far :

```
Long number = ean12;
String inputEan12 = Long.toString(ean12);

if (inputEan12.length() == 12) {
    if (inputEan12.startsWith("02"||"21"||"22"||"23"||"24"||"25"||"26"||"27"||"28"||"29")
        //SOME CODE 
    } else {
        //SOME OTHER CODE
    }

} else if (inputEan12.length() == 11) {
    //SOME MORE CODE

} else {
    System.out.println("All is good!");
}
```

I chose to use the ".startsWith()" method to do my check, thinking it would solve my problem easily. But I can only do one check at a time. It seems that I would need to add an "if" for each beginning/number I want to check. It would turn into a big white elephant...

So I thought of using a table (for example : "String []myTable") to put inside all of my "beginning variables" and to loop on that table. But this startsWith() method doesn't allow me to do that. It seems like my prefix has to be simple.

Any solution or advice to give me to check the beginning of my input easily?

Comment: You can't chain method parameters with an or `||` together. You have to chain the complete method call together: `inputEan12.startsWith("02")||inputEan12.startsWith("21")`

Comment: Put all your possible values in a list (or set), and use Collection.contains(subStr) ?

Comment: Some people, when confronted with a problem, think "I know, I'll use regular expressions." Now they have two problems ;)

Comment: I don't think that when converting long to String you will ever end up with "02" prefix... you may want to rethink your data types.

Comment: thank you for your kind advice @OH GOD SPIDERS. It must be a basic error but i'm still a beginner in Java. So this explains that. Thank you for your help.

Comment: There is a nice solution provided here -> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9790584/how-to-check-if-a-string-starts-with-one-of-several-prefixes

Answer (score 2):

Here it is, hope it's what you're looking for:

```
List<String> possibleValues = Arrays.asList("02", "21", "22", "23", "24", "25", "26", "27", "28", "29");
if (possibleValues.contains(inputEan12.substring(0, 2))) {
         //SOME CODE 
}
```

Comment: For efficiency Set would be probably better than List.

Comment: Agreed, but for convenience, `Arrays.asList(...)` seems way easier

Comment: Since Java 9 we have `Set.of(...)` too. For earlier versions all we need is wrapping list in set like `new HashSet<>(Arrays.asList(...))`.

Comment: Good to know too, and if the OP runs Java 9, it's easier than what I wrote!

Comment: I'm still using Java 8. So your solution was perfect for my case. Thank you, HBo !

Comment: My pleasure. Accept this answer if you feel like it!

Answer (score 1):

you can use `.matches(String regex)` like this :

```
if (inputEan12.matches("^(02|21|22|23|24|25|26|27|28|29).*$"){ }
```

Answer (score 1):

If you're willing to use an external library then Commons Lang [StringUtils.startsWithAny](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/javadocs/api-release/org/apache/commons/lang3/StringUtils.html#startsWithAny-java.lang.CharSequence-java.lang.CharSequence...-) will work:

```
if (StringUtils.startsWithAny(inputEan12, "02", "21", "22", etc...)
{
    // do stuff
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a regular expression.

```
// either "02" or "2 and any number between 1 and 9"
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("(02|2[1-9]).*");
if (inputEan12.length() == 12) {
    if (p.matcher(inputEan).matches()) {
        // code 
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no `or` short syntax like that with `startsWith`. You **could** use multiple calls to `String.startsWith` seperated by `||` (which is logically what you have written). But, it would be shorter to take an array of valid prefixes and the substring of `inputEan12` you care about and use `anyMatch` with `Arrays.stream`. Like,

```
Long number = ean12;
String inputEan12 = Long.toString(ean12);
String[] prefixes = { "02", "21", "22", "23", "24", "25", "26", "27", "28", "29" };
if (inputEan12.length() == 12) {
    String firstTwo = inputEan12.substring(0, 2);
    if (Arrays.stream(prefixes).anyMatch(firstTwo::equals)) {
        // SOME CODE
    } else {
        // SOME OTHER CODE
    }
} else if (inputEan12.length() == 11) {
    // SOME MORE CODE

} else {
    System.out.println("All is good!");
}
```

Comment: Thank you @Elliot Frisch. That really helped me too !

Answer (score 0):

Or simply iterate:

```
public static void main(final String[] args) {
    String inputEan12 = "ean12";

    if (inputEan12.length() == 12) {
        if (startsWith(inputEan12, "02", "21", "22", "23", "24", "25", "26", "27", "28", "29")) {
            //SOME CODE
        } else {
            //SOME OTHER CODE
        }
    }
}

private static boolean startsWith(final String string, final String... possibilities) {
    for (String prefix : possibilities) {
        if (string.startsWith(prefix)) {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```