# Regex to check if a String starts with special characters like "+" , "-" , "=" or "@" Java

Tags: java, regex

I have to write a Regex to check if a String  starts with special characters like "+" , "-" , "=" or "@" in Java.

To check for starting with "+", I've tried :

```
if (value.matches("^\\+.*$")) {
    System.out.println("Hey '"+value);
}
```

I am being unable to use the 'or' in regex for the rest.
I also don't want to check for each character since that would need compilation each time and that would be very slow.

Can anyone please help me out with an optimal regex.

Also would startsWith() be better and faster in this case?

Comment: You may also put those characters in a list, and check if it contains `charAt(0)` from the string.

Comment: Will that be the most optimized solution ?

Comment: Something like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9790627/9758194) older post on SO?

Comment: @JvdV Yes, I was looking for that! Do you have any exact values ?

Comment: @user16320675 Actually this is a part of a solution in a software where performance is a key aspect. Hence any improvement is acceptable and optimal.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To check for the exact 4 special characters you mentioned in your question, use a character class in your regex pattern:

```java
if (value.matches("[+=@-].*")) {
    System.out.println("Hey '" + value);
}
```

Comment: @user16320675 ... or you may escape the `-` with backslashes.